# When is it worth to create a helper function

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, namespaces, wmi

First of all, while the question is phrased around PowerShell, the issue itself has nothing to do with PowerShell, it's a general issue programming question.

I'm creating some PowerShell scripts and I like to separate everything into functions and modules, both so that if I require it again at a later stage I can just port it over, but also so I can share it with the community.

Most times it is very easy to decide whether to create a helper function or not, but sometimes not so much. I am facing one of those issues myself now.

I am doing some work with WMI and noticed that there is no 'logic' way to retrieve a list of existing WMI namespaces (children of a specified namespace).

I thought, wouldn't it be great if I could just call:

```
Get-CimNamespace -Namespace root\cimv2
```

And get a list of child namespaces of root\cimv2? It's incredibly simple to do also, and therein lies the problem...

All that `Get-CimNamespace -Namespace root\cimv2` would be doing is literally... `Get-CimInstance -Class __Namespace -Namespace root\cimv2`.

So one has to ask, what are the advantages of such a function? I can see a couple:

- Using Get-Cim**Instance** to retrieve a namespace does not sound very logical. After all, an instance belongs to a class, and a class to a namespace, so it's sort of like using `Get-CimInstance` to get the parent's parent. It's not, but sort of.
- Having a helper function means users don't have to *know* that namespaces are saved under instances of the class __Namespace. It just works.
- Provides completeness.

But, bearing in mind that `Get-CimInstance` has quite a few other possible arguments, including filters, ability to query remote computers, etc etc... it only really becomes worth having a function such as `Get-CimNamespace` if it is as flexible as calling `Get-CimInstance` directly. This means accepting as many arguments as `Get-CimInstance`, it means having all the parameter sets it has, etc etc.

It seems like quite a lot of work to do to save people having to write `-Class __Namespace` on `Get-CimInstance` so the question is raised... is it worth it?

When does one draw the line? Is it worth to create a function that will just retrieve the properties of a class when you could just do `<WMIClass>.Properties`?

What defines when it's worth it or not to create something like this.

Comment: If you have the time and you really want to do it, then it's worth it.  For people that have full-time software development positions, they don't get to do things just because they really want to--they have to spend their time meeting the requirements that they were given so that the product can hopefully be shipped on time.